# How to read file from asset folder in android using RX in background thread

Tags: android, rx-java

```
private ModelObject model;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    }

    private void readFile() {
        if (model == null) {
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            final String helpItem = “my _file.json”;
            InputStream stream = null;
            try {
                stream = getResources().getAssets().open(helpItem);
                Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream);
                model = gson.fromJson(reader, ModelObjects.class);
                reader.close();
                stream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Timber.w(e);
            } finally {
                fileclose();
            }
        }
    }
```

This is my code using this code i am reading file from assets folder and parse to Model object but i want to read this file in back ground thread  instead of Main thread so  and get data main thread please suggest me how to implement read file in background thread  and  get value in Main thread.

Comment: From memory, but something like `Observable.fromCallable(() -> readFile()).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).subscribe()` should do it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with `Observable` like this:

```
Observable.fromCallable(new Callable<ModelObject>() {
      @Override public ModelObject call() throws Exception {
        return readFile(); // Make readFile so that it returns ModelObject
      }
    })
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(new Observer<ModelObject>() {
          @Override public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

          }

          @Override public void onNext(ModelObject o) {

          }

          @Override public void onError(Throwable e) {

          }

          @Override public void onComplete() {

          }
        });
```

Comment: So this we have to keep in OnCreate method? @Bach Vu

Comment: Anywhere you want

Comment: this are two method or Single method @Bach Vu  can you please   suggest me  because  i am new in RX

Comment: It's a single call, creating an `Observable`, then subscibe to it in `io` thread and listen to it on `mainThread`

Comment: Also, I suggest you reading this https://blog.mindorks.com/understanding-types-of-observables-in-rxjava-6c3a2d0819c8 for knowing when to use which types of `Observable`

Comment: Disposable what does it mean its asking for Import   use other library

Comment: I thought you want to do this RxJava way, so I suppose you already added the library right? https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189565/discussion-between-marsh-and-bach-vu).